# Using a Result by reference if it's Ok

Tags: rust

I want to alter parameters list if some environment variable is set. The parameters list is a vector of tuples with two string slices each.

The code that supposed to do that:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut params = vec![
        // there is a whole list of default params
        ("param", "value"),
    ];

    if let Ok(extra_param) = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM") {
        params.push(("extra_param", &extra_param));
    };

    dbg!(params);
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work because extra_params belongs to the local `if let` scope, and the compiler produces the following error:

```
$ EXTRA_PARAM=extra_value cargo run

error[E0597]: `extra_param` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:37
   |
10 |         params.push(("extra_param", &extra_param));
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
11 |     };
   |     - `extra_param` dropped here while still borrowed
12 |
13 |     dbg!(params);
   |          ------ borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `question` due to previous error
```

I solved this by adding a variable into the outer scope and copying the internal variable's value before referencing it:

```
let external_param;

if let Ok(extra_param) = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM") {
    external_param = extra_param;
    params.push(("extra_param", &external_param));
};
```

Now, my program works as expected, but the solution feels mediocre.

I'm I missing something? Is there any way to get the `Result` so the code would look less clumsy?

I want to solve this without changing types inside tuples, so they still would be string slices, because there are lots of them that are defined in code and I only need one extra parameter to add conditionally.

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=845123dde3b013fe6f1bbbfaf5e1a6f1)

Comment: What is the _explicit_ type of `params`?  Is it `Vec<(&'static str, &'static str)>` or `Vec<(&'static str, String)>`?  Or something else?  I think that will point you to what you want to do, versus what you're doing.  `std::env::var` returns a `Result<String, VarError>`, so I'm wondering what your `Vec` ultimately contains.

Comment: It's defined by assigning  `vec![("param", "value")]'` to it, so it's just `Vec<(&str, &str)>`. Or at least it is what `rust-analyzer` from VSCode prints on the screen.

Comment: Don't remove the lifetimes from what I said.  It's important you realize what lifetimes you're using if your using `&str` instead of `String`.  Your vector owns nothing if it's slices.  And if some are `static` lifetime, that matters.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for that case, when you have a lot of reference outsides and very little inside.

Comment: This is a good solution because it really properly indicates for how much time you want the underlying `str` to live. You could also leak the `String` into a `&'static str`, but then it means it would live forever, as opposed to living for the scope of the variable `external_param`, which is more easily controllable.

Comment: So you have a large list of default params and you want to be able to override them with environment variables? Is that basically it?

Comment: If you have a lot of these, instead of the local extra variable you can use `Cow`, like in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6f760a877a046ebde4198be96d65302c).

Comment: Instead of Cow I could hav used `Vec<&str, String>` but that would mean I'd have to write a lots of `String::from` for default params and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three solution you could use:

Create the `Result` as a variable outside of if let statement:

```
let envvar = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM");
if let Ok(ref extra_param) = envvar {
    params.push(("extra_param", extra_param));
}
```

Use the fact that `Option` and `Result` implement `Iterator` to `extend` the `Vec` if `envvar` is `Ok`:

```
let envvar = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM");
params.extend(envvar.as_ref().map(|extra| ("extra_param", extra.as_str())));
```

Change the `params` `Vec` to own `String` instead of `&str`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut params = vec![
        // there is a whole list of default params
        ("param", "value".to_owned()),
    ];

    if let Ok(extra_param) = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM") {
        // now extra param is moved into params instead of borrowed
        params.push(("extra_param", extra_param));
    };

    // or use this instead of if let
    params.extend(env::var("EXTRA_PARAM").map(|extra_param| ("extra_param", extra_param)));

    dbg!(params);
}
```

Comment: The third answer is what I want to avoid, since I don't want to change string literals to something else. The second one is cool, but not very readable if you compare it with the first one. The first one is perfect, thanks! I learned Rust using The Book, and it seems `ref` is not explained there, and I haven't stumbled upon it yet by myself.

Comment: `Ok(ref extra_param) = envvar` should be the same as `Ok(extra_param) = envvar.as_ref()`. It says you want to borrow the content of the `Ok` variant, not move it. You should also be able to do `ref mut` (or maybe its `mut ref` I don't know from the top of my head)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I got to my question, it seems OK if I use the external variable. The only more concise way I found is to extract the parameter first using `unwrap_or_default` and to compare it with an empty string in the condition:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut params = vec![
        // there is a whole list of default params
        ("param", "value"),
    ];

    let extra_param = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM").unwrap_or_default();

    if extra_param != "" {
        params.push(("extra_param", &extra_param));
    };

    dbg!(params);
}
```

It makes even more sense if I decide to extract `params` into a separate function, because extracting the value from `Result` inside would mean creating a local variable, so I couldn't return a reference to the parameter this way:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let extra_param = env::var("EXTRA_PARAM").unwrap_or_default();

    let params = build_params(&extra_param);

    dbg!(params);
}

fn build_params<'a>(extra_param: &'a String) -> Vec<(&'static str, &'a str)> {
    let mut params = vec![
        // there is a whole list of default params
        ("param", "value"),
    ];

    if extra_param != "" {
        params.push(("extra_param", extra_param));
    };

    params
}
```